# Wifi stopped getting connected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, password, authentication

My Ubuntu 20.04 was working all fine, but all of a sudden I am not able to connect to my wifi as it is keeps on asking me for the wifi password again and again.

I tried to remove the wifi password in my phone and make it public, and the open wifi was possible to connect, but I can't remove the password of my ISP wifi modem.

I tried so many fixes in different answers of this website, but I had no luck.

This is the image of the pop-up.

[image: This is the image of the pop up]

Comment: Are you sure you typed the password correctly?  Check caps lock and num lock?  Reboot both devices?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure and I have rebooted wifi and even restarted laptop many times but no luck.